# Is there any possibility in triggering the intent without the help of Training phrases?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have created 5 intents in a Dialog flow. After completion of first intent, it should automatically go to the second intent without the use of the training phase. Is there any possibility to do that?

Answer (score 1):

This probably isn't what you want to do. Remember that Intents capture *what the user says or does* and not how Dialogflow should respond.

If you want to do a series of things when the user says one thing, then you can do all those things in your fulfillment webhook. Your webhook is where you actually *do* something based on what the user has said, and this can be handled in one function call or several calls that you make from your Intent Handler.

Comment: what do you mean about "doing all those things in the fulfillment webhook"?

Comment: I've updated my answer to hopefully clarify further, but it may help if you updated your question to show an example that illustrates what you are trying to do, what you have tried that doesn't work, or what your code and Intents look like.

Comment: Thanks but I have found the answer.

Comment: You can help others with similar questions by posting the solution you found as an answer.

Comment: @SravyaGajavalli can you post the solution?

Comment: @AugustoCoelhoHenriques - given the age of the question, if you have a similar issue you may wish to post it as a new question specifying what you've tried and as many other details as possible.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities either you can use contexts or if you want to handle sequence from webhook service you can use events.

**For webhook solution,**
Give each Intent a specific event and action.

In your webhook request you will get action of your intent and you can trigger next event based on current action. => [Dialogflow](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dialogflow)

**For context solution**
You can add Follow up intents for your each intents, [Follow-up-intents](https://dialogflow.com/docs/contexts/follow-up-intents)

Comment: I have tried these two methods but did not work i.e the intent did not get started unless you give the triggering word of that intent.

Comment: no, you can trigger intent by sending events, while triggering intent with event you dont need to pass triggering word. You are missing something please check, or update your question with your code and screenshot

Comment: Ok can you tell me how do we call the follow-up intent from fulfillment webhook

Comment: I found the solution.